# navigating to a particular block in xsl upon certain conditions

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an condition in xsl in which I have to read the data if sert name is gfrt and the value is TTT can you please advise how would the xsl:if tag for this..

```
<abcData name="aaa" idref="egh">
 <sert name="gfrt" idref="tre">TTT</sert>
  <sert name="ghhrt" idref="rew">R</sert>
</abcData>
```

I have gone through this way...

```
<xsl:if test="./@name=$gfrt">
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<xsl:template match="sert">
    <xsl:if test="@name='gfrt' and .='TTT'">
        Do something here...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="abcData">
    <xsl:for-each select="sert">
        <xsl:if test="@name='gfrt' and .='TTT'">
            Do something here...
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

it depends on which context you are in.